# When would I use an alias on a using Directive?

Tags: c#

So I was reading over the MSDN docs and came across:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

What is a practical use of using an alias for `using` directives?

I get what is does, I just dont get WHY I could want to use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's useful if you have a class of the same name in two different namespaces.  When that happens you have two choices.  `using` one namespace and not another (meaning use the fully qualified name for the other one), or `using` one namespace normally and `using` another with an alias.  Since the alias is shorter than the fully qualified name it's still easier and more convenient.

Obviously the best option is to just not have public classes of the same name in different namespaces, especially if there's any chance someone would want to use both in the same class.

Answer (score 8):

For example you might be using in your class 2 other classes with the same name but in different namespaces. For example:

```
 using TextBoxForms = System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
 using TextBoxWeb = System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
```

Answer (score 5):

I like to use it for generics as sometimes writing them out can be very wordy.

```
using NatMap = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<IPAddress, IPAddress[]>;
...
NatMap natMap = new NatMap();
```

When using a function:

```
void PrintNat(NatMap natMap) {
    foreach (IPAddress[] addresses in natMap) {
        foreach (IPaddress address in addresses) {
            // bla bla bla
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is useful, the `var` keyword can also reduce the amount of typing in these situations.

Answer (score 4):

There are two really good reasons to use it:

1. There's a name collision (two classes in separate namespaces with the same name). Instead of writing out the fully-qualified type (including the full namespace), you can alias one of them to be a much shorter but equally descriptive name instead.

   a. Example: Let's say you have a project that contains a class `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` and you're also using System.Collections.Generic for something else. You could alias your class with `using MyStringIntPair = MyProject.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, int>` and you're code will look a lot cleaner for not having `MyProject.Collections.Generic` all over the place.
2. Native interop. I've personally found this very useful when dealing with the native `long` type. On most operating systems, a `long` is the same size as a pointer, but on Windows 64-bit, it's the same as an int. So for most operating systems, I can represent a `long` as an `IntPtr`, but it needs to change for Windows 64-bit, so I create a type alias and change the definition of it with a preprocessor directive.

   a. FreeType uses `long` quite a bit, so when I wrote up bindings for it, I had to make it work on Windows 64-bit as well. I was considering some sort of dynamic subclassing based on the OS, but the preprocessor directive and type aliases were simpler and got the job done for now. [An example would be the FT_BBox struct, which uses longs](https://github.com/Robmaister/SharpFont/blob/master/SharpFont/Internal/BBoxRec.cs).

Simplified, relevant version of the FT_BBox struct below:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

#if WIN64
using FT_Pos = System.Int32;
#else
using FT_Pos = System.IntPtr;
#endif

namespace SharpFont.Internal
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Internally represents a BBox.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Refer to <see cref="BBox"/> for FreeType documentation.
    /// </remarks>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct BBoxRec
    {
        internal FT_Pos xMin, yMin;
        internal FT_Pos xMax, yMax;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From that link

> Create a using alias to make it easier to qualify an identifier to a namespace or type. The right side of a using alias directive must always be a fully-qualified type regardless of the using directives that come before it.

So you might change a type from

```
Foo.Bar.Foo.Bar.Foo.Bar.Foo.Bar.Foo.Bar.Foo.Bar
```

To something more manageable like

```
FooBar
```

Particularly if you have multiple namespaces that clash

Answer (score 3):

You can for example use it when you want short names for two classes with the same name from different namespaces. If you specify the namespaces the class names conflict, so you can give them different names:

```
using ImageControl = System.Windows.Controls.Image;
using Image = System.Drawing.Image;
```